# Working with div tags and php include

Tags: php, html

This is probably a basic question on something I didn't learn in my self-taught html. In my index.html I have a div calling a php file like so:

```
    <div id="portafolio" /> 
<p class="first">Portafolio</p>
<p class="second">Estos son algunos de nuestros proyectos.</p>

<?php include 'portafolio.html'; ?>

<!-end #portafolio ->
</div>
```

Inside the php file, there is some javascript and  more div tags like so:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function(){

$("img.a").hover(
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
},
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
});

});
</script>

<div class="fadehover">
<img src="images/motmotcoffee/motmotcoffee_1BW.jpg" alt="" class="a" />
<img src="images/motmotcoffee/motmotcoffee_1.jpg" alt="" class="b" />
</div>
```

I expect the printed html from the php file to be included inside  which has top and bottom borders defined in the CSS, but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: Is your server configured to process `.html` as PHP?

Comment: What's exactly the problem? is it within your CSS code(loaded HTML doesn't have borders) or within PHP(HTML file isn't loaded)?

Comment: The problem is in the CSS styling itself. The printed HTML from the included PHP file is not within the <div id="portafolio" /> styling, which has borders around it.

Answer (score 3):

Change the extension of your files to `.php`, modify your include statement accordingly and that should work.
Your server is probably not configured to process `.html` files as php files.

**Update:**

Your `<div id="portafolio" />` tag is self-closing, so there won't be anything inside it...
Change it to `<div id="portafolio">`

Comment: The include html files print fine, because there's no php code inside the html files. So that's working.

The problem is in the CSS styling itself. The printed HTML from the included PHP file is not within the <div id="portafolio" /> styling, which has borders around it.

Comment: `<div id="portafolio" />` try removing the closing `/` -> `<div id="portafolio">`